# Updating state managed by another reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

In my React app, my `appReducer` manages global stuff such as notifications, user info, etc.

One of the modules in the app is the inventory module which has its own reducer i.e. `inventoryReducer`. And in the redux store, I combine all the reducers.

When a user makes an inventory entry, in addition to handling the inventory transaction, I want to display an on-screen notification which is handled in the `appReducer`. How do I update the state of `displayNotification` which is under `appReducer` from the `inventoryReducer`?

The following is my app reducer:

```js
import 'babel-polyfill';
import * as types from '../actions/actionTypes';

const initialState = {
    displayNotification: {}
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    
    switch (action.type) {

        case types.DISPLAY_NOTIFICATION : 
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                displayNotification: action.value
            })

        default: return state
    }
}
```

And this is the `inventoryReducer`:

```js
import 'babel-polyfill';
import * as types from '../actions/actionTypes';

const initialState = {
    inventory: []
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    
    switch (action.type) {

        case types.SET_INVENTORY : 
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                inventory: action.inventoryItem
            })

        case types.DISPLAY_NOTIFICATION : 
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                app.displayNotification: action.value // <-- Is this how I access `displayNotification` which is managed by the `appReducer`?
                })
    
            default: return state
        }
    }
```

My update inventory action needs to dispatch both `SET_INVENTORY` and `DISPLAY_NOTIFICATION`. I'm trying to understand how I can update `displayNotification` from `inventoryReducer` where `displayNotification` is actually managed by the `appReducer`.

Comment: I think what you're trying to do is the wrong approach. What's stopping you from a) listening to `SET_INVENTORY` in your appReducer or b) dispatch both actions from your component?

Comment: If I were to listen to SET_INVENTORY in appReducer, things would get out of control very quickly as the number of modules increases in the app. The appReducer would get completely bloated and the purpose of creating separate reducers would be out the window. As per your second suggestion, I could dispatch both actions in my component but then I'm shifting the logic into the component. I think this should be handled in the action creator. Last but not least, the pluralSight course instructor indicates that multiple reducers can resonde to a given action.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Following up with what [azium](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3225108/azium) [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40900354/updating-state-managed-by-another-reducer#comment69014973_40900354):

> I think what you're trying to do is the wrong approach. What's stopping you from a) listening to `SET_INVENTORY` in your appReducer or b) dispatch both actions from your component?

As far as I understand, in Redux each reducer is allocated a slice of the entire state object and their operations are restricted in that slice. They are not allowed to access the state slice managed by any other reducer, and they **shouldn't** do that.

The concept description of Redux is that it is a *predictable state container*. But when I look at what we are trying to achieve in this question, if we were to access/modify state managed by another reducer-B in our reducer-A, the predictability and maintainability of the app are compromised according to me.

Without compromising on anything or moving undesired logic into our components, we can achieve what we need.

#### Option 1

Inside `appReducer`

you create a type `SET_INVENTORY` which does what `DISPLAY_NOTIFICATION` does. You can have multiple subscriptions for the single action that dispatches type `SET_INVENTORY` (in `appReducer` and `inventoryReducer`).

As shown below, in `appReducer`, if the action type is either `SET_INVENTORY` or `DISPLAY_NOTIFICATION`, the reducer updates the key `displayNotification`.

```
export default (state = initialState, action) => {

    switch (action.type) {

        case types.SET_INVENTORY : 
        case types.DISPLAY_NOTIFICATION : 
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                displayNotification: action.value
            })

        default: return state
    }
}
```

#### Option 2

Create a method that couples the dispatching of two actions,

let's say you have an action

```
function setInventory(inventoryItem) {
    return {
        type: types.SET_INVENTORY,
        inventoryItem
    };
}
```

and another action

```
function displayNotification(value) {
    return {
        type: types.DISPLAY_NOTIFICATION,
        value,
    };
}
```

create a thunk to couple them:

```
export function notifyAndSetInventory(notify, inventoryItem) {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(displayNotification(notify));
        return dispatch(setInventory(inventoryItem));
    };
}
```

Comment: Option 2 is exactly what I'm "trying" to do. However, the question is where is this thunk and how does it dispatch two actions that manage two separate slices of the state. I actually asked the course instructor this question and my initial approach was to simply import the DISPLAY_NOTIFICATION action into inventoryActions and dispatch it from there. He said, this would work but he recommended a different approach. His exact words about the approach he recommends are "handling a given action in multiple reducers". I'm now trying to understand what this means and how to implement it.

Comment: My take on this is that the action is the same action and it's handled by two separate reducers. If notifications is the responsibility of the appReducer AND we'll be calling DISPLAY_NOTIFICATION action from inventoryReducer, that means we're accessing notifications from inventoryReducer. I'll ask for more clarification.

Comment: "handling a given action in multiple reducers"; may be he meant **option 1**. Reducers are meant for state reduction, they shouldn't dispatch actions.  Create thunks to couple actions targeting different reducers or responding to a state change.

Comment: You're absolutely correct -- again! He just gave me a response and he thought I was referring to two different slices of the state. Your option 1 is the correct answer. Thank you!

Comment: @free-soul Option 1 looks great, but what could I do if the component that dispatches **SET_INVENTORY** doesn't have access to the payload that **DISPLAY_NOTIFICATION** needs?

Answer (score 8):

In Redux's official document there's a chapter called *'Beyond combineReducers'*. It mentioned sharing data between slice reducers.

[Sharing data between slice reducers](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/beyond-combinereducers#sharing-data-between-slice-reducers)

I personally prefer the third solution mentioned in the link, which is adding a third customized reducer to handle the "special" cases where data needs to be shared across slices, then use [reduce-reducers](https://github.com/redux-utilities/reduce-reducers) to combine the new customized reducer and the original combined reducer (i.e. `appReducer` + `inventoryReducer`).

```js
const crossSliceReducer = (state, action) => {
  if (action.type === 'CROSS_SLICE_ACTION') {
    // You can access both app and inventory states here
  }
  return state;
}
// Combine the reducers like you did before
const combinedReducer({app: appReducer, inventory: inventoryReducer});

// Add the cross-slice reducer to the root reducer
const rootReducer = reduceReducers(combinedReducer, crossSliceReducer)
```